# Powerpoint Activex Control hyperlink to different slide

Tags: vba, hyperlink, controls, activex, powerpoint

I am trying to have a button in PowerPoint that will jump to different slides depending on a set of toggle or option buttons. The buttons are on the slide master to maintain the selections throughout the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If SlideMaster.optBlah.Value = True Then
       SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide 2
    Else
       SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide 3
    End If

End Sub
```